# Docker secrets secure?

Tags: linux, security, docker, encryption

I was wondering about the security level of Docker secrets as they are considered secure. When I grant a service access to a secret, as expected, I can witness a tempfs mounted on the container path (`/var/lib/docker/containers/<container ID>/mounts/secrets`) on the node hosting the service's task. However, I was able to cat the file inside this path and see the secret's content.

At that point I was wondering, what makes secrets more secure than configs. To my knowledge the fact that they are stored in RAM disks is the key difference between them and configs. Both configs and secrets are encrypted inside raft, the only difference is that configs stored in files on disks while mounted to containers as opposed to secrets which reside on RAM disks. But if I can view the content of the secrets, does it really makes a difference?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, *being secure* is not aneasy term. I would rather speak about *risk assessment* and *risk acceptance*. Everything is about answering the questions, how much paranoid you are; what kind of solution you claim to be secure.

[Per documentation,](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/) we have:

> *When you add a secret to the swarm, Docker sends the secret to the swarm manager over a mutual TLS connection. The secret is stored in the Raft log, which is encrypted. The entire Raft log is replicated across the other managers, ensuring the same high availability guarantees for secrets as for the rest of the swarm management data.*

**Secrets availability.** Per container [ephemerallity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/ephemeral-containers/).
You never know the node, where your container is up and running, and you should not care about it much. Said that, this secrets should be available everywhere, where container runs.

**Secrets in memory.** There is kind of write-up about keeping secrets in memory, [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29019/are-passwords-stored-in-memory-safe). The problem is... if you do not trust your system and its memory management, you have way bigger problem, than just password kept in memory.

**Difference.**

- Secrets in file are generally in kept plaintext. [wp-config](https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/) It is way better to keep them persistent encrypted, and non-encrypted in memory only.
- Secrets should be [rotated](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/#example-rotate-a-secret).

Said that, you can achieve *almost* same thing, by keeping you secret file encrypted with [openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16056298/11466980), decrypt it and put non-encrypted content in memory. Everything of that you would do manually.